# pulling in html (json string) into javascript

Tags: ajax, http-get

i am trying to pull an html page into my javascript file, (essentaiily the webpage will consist of a JSON string) and then i would like to set that string to a js var for eval.  i have tried the $.ajax method - currently to no avail.

Comment: What `dataType` option are you using with $.ajax ? It should be 'json'

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.getJSON('my.json', function (obj) {
    MyNS.Sub.doSomething(obj);
});
```

Comment: depends if you call it in ASYNC mode or not.

Comment: actually maybe it doesn't even return the object when async = false.